# Keep the Ubuntu package version I'm using now

Tags: installation, package-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to prevent updating of a specific package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package)

I just installed a package (wine). I want to keep this version I'm using now. How can I disable updates for this package?

Thank you in advance.