# How do I hold back a Firefox update in kPackageKit?

Tags: kubuntu, apt

Recently in my kubuntu 10.10 a firefox update showed which is about 15.2mb, but I already have 8.0.

And it works fine with forecastfox 2.21 of which is has problems I see thru forecastfox users groups doesn't work with firefox 9.01, so how do I not do this update thru kpackagekit, and delete from the kpackagekit?

Answer (score 1):

The Ubuntu community documentation has: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto

> This wiki page will discuss some advanced things you can do to
>   packages to accomplish specific goals. The first thing described is
>   Pinning, this is useful if you want only some things from a newer
>   version of Ubuntu. There is also package holding, which allows you to
>   not update the package.

More links:

- http://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?54069-FAQ-Pinning-Holding-Locking-packages
- [Keep the Ubuntu package version I'm using now](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86226/keep-the-ubuntu-package-version-im-using-now)
- [How to prevent updating of a specific package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package)