# Exclude packages from `apt-get upgrade`

Tags: package-management, apt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to prevent updating of a specific package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package)
>   [Keep the Ubuntu package version I'm using now](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86226/keep-the-ubuntu-package-version-im-using-now)

Is it possible to upgrade all packages except a given package? Is there something like `apt-get upgrade --exclude package_to_exclude`?

Comment: Actually you can do this with several methods, see the link I gave you above.

Answer (score 205, accepted):

**To hold a package**:

In short: `sudo apt-mark hold <package>`

or

```
echo <package> hold | sudo dpkg --set-selections
```

**To unhold a package**:

In short: `sudo apt-mark unhold <package>`

or

```
echo <package> install | sudo dpkg --set-selections
```

Comment: I get the following error: `Usage: apt-mark [options] {markauto|unmarkauto} packages...

apt-mark: error: first argument must be 'markauto', 'unmarkauto' or 'showauto'`

Comment: Strange. It works for me. Just tried it using `sudo apt-mark hold unity-greeter`

Comment: I think this error has to do with the Ubuntu version. Versions prior to 12.04 don't support apt-mark hold

Comment: Once the package should be updated again, use the unhold parameter.

Comment: Also, `sudo apt-mark showhold` will show that it is now on hold. (Note: that isn't `showhole`, that's a Netflix error state.)

Comment: 2 things work noticing: 1. You can specify many packages: apt-mark package1 package2 ...
2. Holded packages also works with apt-get upgrade if someone's still using it ;)

Answer (score 7):

Check out "Introduction to Holding Packages" in the Ubuntu's [Pinning Howto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto)