# Software updater reverting to previous kernel version

Tags: kernel, update-manager

I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I have updated it to the latest stable Ubuntu kernel:

```
Linux version 3.17.1-031701-generic (apw@gomeisa) (gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) ) #201410150735 SMP Wed Oct 15 11:36:31 UTC 2014
```

This is the output when I run: 
    cat /proc/version

When I run the software updater, I automatically revert to the 3.13 ..... version of the kernel. Is there any way that I can update software's without reverting to the kernels previous version?

Thank, 
Rochan

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
sudo apt-mark hold [linuxkernelpackage]
```

This will ignore upgrades/downgrades for that package.

Source: [Exclude packages from `apt-get upgrade`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/99774/exclude-packages-from-apt-get-upgrade)

Answer (score 0):

The latest official kernel for 14.04LTS is 3.13, you must have installed the 3.17 kernel using a PPA or from scratch.

Comment: Yes I have, That is what I did but every time I used software updater, it de/down-graded. Anyway, thanks for the help.