# Ubuntu automatically installed a previous kernel version than the one I installed

Tags: kernel, downgrade, unattended-upgrades

I manually installed kernel `4.2.0-38` on Ubuntu `14.04.4`.

This morning, Ubuntu automatically reinstalled `3.13.0.91`.

```
Start-Date: 2016-06-28  06:33:35
Install: linux-headers-3.13.0-91:amd64 (3.13.0-91.138, automatic), linux-image-extra-3.13.0-91-generic:amd64 (3.13.0-91.138, automatic), linux-image-3.13.0-91-generic:amd64 (3.13.0-91.138, automatic), linux-headers-3.13.0-91-generic:amd64 (3.13.0-91.138, automatic)
Upgrade: linux-headers-generic:amd64 (3.13.0.88.94, 3.13.0.91.97), linux-libc-dev:amd64 (3.13.0-88.135, 3.13.0-91.138), linux-image-generic:amd64 (3.13.0.88.94, 3.13.0.91.97), linux-generic:amd64 (3.13.0.88.94, 3.13.0.91.97)
End-Date: 2016-06-28  06:37:08
```

I have read a solution to the problem [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/541275/software-updater-reverting-to-previous-kernel-version), but I would like to understand what happened exactly and why.

Isn't 4.2 officially supported by `14.04.4`?

EDIT: I forgot to provide a piece of information: at the next boot, I would actually go into the 3.19 kernel (this is actually the big problem, I wouldn't mind otherwise):

```
vpii@hw10:~$ ls -l /vmlinuz
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 30 Jun 28 04:33 /vmlinuz -> boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-91-generic
vpii@hw10:~$ ls -l /vmlinuz.old
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Jun 24 10:49 /vmlinuz.old -> boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-38-generic
```

Comment: But you still boot with 4.2.0-38. You did not remove the meta package.

Comment: I think I would boot into 3.19, that's where /vmlinuz points to. I edited the question to add this information.

Comment: You can check it by `uname -a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want `apt` to upgrade the 3.13 kernels, remove meta packages by

```
sudo apt-get remove linux-image-generic linux-headers-generic
```

If you want to get updates for the 4.2 kernel, install the meta package for it by

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-wily
```

The 4.2 is shipped with Ubuntu 14.04.4 by default. You have older meta packages because you installed Ubuntu before 14.04.4 has been released, or installed `linux-image-generic` manually following some guide.

Comment: Thanks. If I just add the wily updates and don't remove `linux-image-generic` and `linux-headers-generic`, I will have the same problem everytime a new kernel in the 3.13 series will be released?

Comment: Yes, you will get 3.13 updates. But it is not a problem ;-)