# Does Ubuntu 14.04 support PHP, Mysql, Apache?

Tags: 14.04, server, apache2, php, mysql

**Versions are:**

- Ubuntu server version is 10.04
- PHP version is 5.4.7
- Mysql version is 5.1.69
- Apache server version is 2.4.3

Now, I would like to update to Ubuntu 14.04 but no update PHP, Mysql and Apache. If I update, is there any compatibility issue?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! One note to add, as this is your first post, try to make sure everything is easy to read for the helpers to understand what you mean.

Comment: please check and confirm whether below versions support for Ubuntu 14.04 without any compatibility issues.
 
PHP                     : 5.4.7
MySQL                   : 5.1.69
Apache Web Server       : Apache 2.4.3

Comment: The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *edit* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

Open terminal (by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install tasksel
```

after finish run this command

```
sudo tasksel
```

then select lamp using space bar and go on the installing instructions.

Comment: -1 This doesn't go into the need to maintain the exact current versions of the packages of the LAMPP stack as described in the question. OP isn't asking how to install *any* LAMPP version after the release upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have them, do a dist-upgrade without touching those existing packages [Exclude packages from `apt-get upgrade`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/99774/exclude-packages-from-apt-get-upgrade)

Comment: If your answer is essentially a referral to another question, it would be better to flag this question as a duplicate of the other (with the [flag] button below this one).

Comment: I don't believe it's a duplicate. It might have a similar solution, but it won't be clear why it's a duplicate unless you already know the answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Please check this URL it will tell you how to do it and use very easy way**

[How To Set Up the Ubuntu 14.* Included X-Windows(xUbuntu) / MySql / PHP (Apache 2 ) In VMware](https://askubuntu.com/questions/729014/how-to-setup-ubuntu-14-included-desktopxubuntu-mysql-php-apache-2-in/729015#729015)

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be a compatibility issue with Ubuntu 14.04. If you upgrade, your server software will be updated too. (If you specifically don't want to upgrade the server software, then don't upgrade Ubuntu because trying to use an older version of software with a newer Ubuntu version is always a fight against the package manager.)