# How to turn off updates for Rhythmbox

Tags: rhythmbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to prevent updating of a specific package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package)
>   [Keep the Ubuntu package version I'm using now](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86226/keep-the-ubuntu-package-version-im-using-now)
>   [Exclude packages from `apt-get upgrade`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/99774/exclude-packages-from-apt-get-upgrade)

**As of today (8/5/12), I tried both suggestions, and it does not seem to work. I have even tried re-starting my computer, and it doesn't seem to work.**

I originally asked a question about how to un-install Rhythmbox... In that question, I also asked how do I turn off updates for Rhythmbox... That never got answered.

When I updated from Ubuntu 11.10 to Ubuntu 12.04, you guy's replaced Banshee with Rhythmbox... Well, I like Banshee better, so when I uninstalled it, next time Update Manager opens, it gives me a bunch of "updates" for Rhythmbox... which includes re-installing it... how do I stop this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you ever tried this steps?

- [Exclude packages from `apt-get upgrade`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/99774/exclude-packages-from-apt-get-upgrade)

In short:

```
sudo apt-mark hold <package>
```

or

```
echo <package> hold | sudo dpkg --set-selections
```

Answered by Zoke.

Comment: Found out how, because of your answer. For anyone trying to learn how to do this, the Terminal command is `sudo apt-mark hold rhythmbox`

Answer (score 4):

You are getting updates because configuration files are still in system. You should also remove Rhythmbox Configuration files. For that type in terminal

```
sudo dpkg -P rhythmbox
```

or

```
sudo dpkg --purge rhythmbox
```

It removes your Package with configuration files perfectly.

Comment: Just an FYI, when you are typing the commands, try to make sure the S in "sudo" is not capitalized... for us "copy and paster's" it tells us the command is invalid. If you put lower case s, it comes out correctly