# upgrading ubuntu 16 to 18 : how to keep a specific version of a library?

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, 18.04, versions

I have ubuntu 16 and I would like to upgrade to the last one, 18.
but I installed sikulix and it requires a specific version (2.4) of a library( opencv)
I know, having tested, that on a fresh installation, that on ubuntu 18 the version 3 is installed by default. I don't know if the new version of this library will replace the old one by upgrading, that's something I would like to avoid.

Will v2.4 be replaced?
If so, how to avoid it?

thank you.

EDIT
before upgrading, I have a big doubt: what about other dependencies? Is there a quicker way than collecting all the dependencies of sikulix and mark them as not to be updated? and what about dependencies of these dependencies? :-(

thank you

Answer (score 1):

You want to

1. Get details about [opencv package in Bionic](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/bionic/opencv)
2. [prevent updating of a specific package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package)
3. [Keep the Ubuntu package version you're using now](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86226/keep-the-ubuntu-package-version-im-using-now)

Comment: thanks, I have not tried but point 2 seems to achieve the stuff. more comments to come if I meet some issue.

Comment: plz have a look at my edit